# CSGO keep inventory next round

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Im on my own server with friends and we want to play wingman but with exojump boots. Each of us performes `exojump` in the console to gather the boots. We need to do this at the beginning of each round. What do I have to do that we keep the boots for the next round?